# Manipulating values in a list (URL) - Python

Tags: python, scrapy

I would like to re-format value from a list. I am trying to extract urls from a website with scrapy. Scrapy returns relative URL which are then stored in the list. I would like to join absolute url with relative url and do some match and replace in relative url within list itself which would then be used for next step.

This is how current list looks like:

```
regions = ['/listings/in/spain%2Fandalucia', '/listings/in/spain%2Faragon', '/listings/in/spain%2Fasturias', '/listings/in/spain%2Fbalearic-islands']
```

**And this is how it would look ideally.**

```
regions_final = ['https://worldmap.com/listings/in/spain/andalucia', 'http://worldmap.comlistings/in/spain/Faragon', 'http://worldmap.comlistings/in/spain/fasturias', 'http://worldmap.com/listings/in/spain/balearic-islands']
```

I would need a simple find and replace of "%2F" for "/" and append "https://worldmap.com" in front of the current values.
If anyone has any tips I would very appreciate the help!

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a more robust way to create the URL:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

region_urls = [response.urljoin(unquote(x)) for x in regions]
```

[`urljoin`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.urljoin) takes care of creating the correct absolute URL based on whatever the current response's base URL is, plus the relative URL.

[`unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) takes care of the `%..` symbols, in case you get others as well.

Comment: Even more elegant: `region_urls = [response.urljoin(unquote(x)) for x in regions]`

Comment: Thank you for this malberts!

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension and adding strings:

```
regions = ['/listings/in/spain%2Fandalucia', '/listings/in/spain%2Faragon', '/listings/in/spain%2Fasturias', '/listings/in/spain%2Fbalearic-islands']

region_urls = ['https://www.worldmap.com' + x.replace('%2F', '/') for x in regions]
#['https://www.worldmap.com/listings/in/spain/andalucia',
# 'https://www.worldmap.com/listings/in/spain/aragon',
# 'https://www.worldmap.com/listings/in/spain/asturias',
# 'https://www.worldmap.com/listings/in/spain/balearic-islands']
```

Comment: @MatijaŽiberna You have accepted a solution that will fail immediately you as soon as any other encoded character appears in the URL. Go with the answer that suggests `urllib`.

Comment: Thank you @Jondiedoop. The solution worked but I went with malberts since it's more robust. Cheers